# Unexpected multiple returns in Python 3 for single variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a little code so people can input a date. The error check that stops a month being entered which is less than 1 or greater than 12 should return a value only when it is within these bounds. If I enter a few 'out of bounds' numbers, it correctly re-asks for a month to be re-entered but returns all the values. What is going on?

```
# the question asked to get the month input for the xml updater
def month_q():
    try:
        month = int(input('What was the month [MM] which the installers were  updated/created by xxx?:'))
    except:
        print("That was not a valid number. Please re-enter a 2 digit month")
        month_q()
    updatemonth = month_check(month)
    print("Month q returning:", updatemonth)
    return updatemonth


# check the update month is a valid month
def month_check(month):
    if month < 1:
        print("The month must be a number between 01 and 12. Please re-enter")
        month_q()
    elif month > 12:
        print("The month must be a number between 01 and 12. Please re-enter")
        month_q()
    else:
        print("Month_check returning month:", month)
        return month



# this updates the xml file with the date of the last installer    
def xml_updater():
    updatemonth = month_q()
    print("Update month:", updatemonth)


xml_updater()
```

The result is of entering bad months '15', '14' and '13' before entering a correct one '12' is:

```
What was the month [MM] which the installers were updated/created by xxx?:15
The month must be a number between 01 and 12. Please re-enter
What was the month [MM] which the installers were updated/created by xxx?:14
The month must be a number between 01 and 12. Please re-enter
What was the month [MM] which the installers were updated/created by xxx?:13
The month must be a number between 01 and 12. Please re-enter
What was the month [MM] which the installers were updated/created by xxx?:12
Month_check returning month: 12
Month q returning: 12
Month q returning: None
Month q returning: None
Month q returning: None
Update month: None
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not returning anything; it is calling the question function again and again, but ignores the return value:

```
def month_check(month):
    if month < 1:
        print("The month must be a number between 01 and 12. Please re-enter")
        month_q()
    elif month > 12:
        print("The month must be a number between 01 and 12. Please re-enter")
        month_q()
    else:
        print("Month_check returning month:", month)
        return month
```

If month is smaller than 1 or greater than 12 the function will return `None` (the default). The statement `updatemonth = month_check(month)` then assigns `None` to `updatemonth` and when `print("Month q returning:", updatemonth)` runs it prints `Month q returning: None`. But since you called `month_q` recursively, that is then returned to the previous `month_check()` call, which returns `None` again, and so forth.

Here is a nested trace of your functions, as `month_q` calls `month_check` calls `month_q`, etc.:

```
month_q():
    What was the month [MM] which the installers were updated/created by xxx?:15
    month_check(15):
        The month must be a number between 01 and 12. Please re-enter
        month_q():
            What was the month [MM] which the installers were updated/created by xxx?:14
            month_check(15):
                The month must be a number between 01 and 12. Please re-enter
                month_q():
                    What was the month [MM] which the installers were updated/created by xxx?:13
                    month_check(13):
                        The month must be a number between 01 and 12. Please re-enter
                        month_q():
                            What was the month [MM] which the installers were updated/created by xxx?:12
                            month_check(12):
                                Month_check returning month: 12
                                <- 12
                            Month q returning: 12
                            <- 12
                        <- None
                    Month q returning: None
                    <- None
                <- None
            Month q returning: None
            <- None
        <- None
    Month q returning: None
    <- None
Update month: None
```

Instead, have the check function return True or False to indicate correct results, and leave the asking for a re-enter to `month_q`.

Do that with a `while` loop instead of recursion though; if you have to ask often enough, you'll end up with a recursion-too-deep exception.

```
def month_q():
    while True:
        try:
            month = int(input('What was the month [MM] which the installers were  updated/created by xxx?:'))
            if not month_check(month):
                raise ValueError()
        except ValueError:
            print("Please re-enter a 2 digit month")
            continue
        print("Month q returning:", month)
        return month


# check the update month is a valid month
def month_check(month):
    if month < 1 or month > 12:
        print("The month must be a number between 01 and 12")
        return False
    return True
```

You may as well inline that check:

```
def month_q():
    while True:
        try:
            month = int(input('What was the month [MM] which the installers were  updated/created by xxx?:'))
            if month < 1 or month > 12:
                raise ValueError()
        except ValueError:
            print("Please re-enter a 2 digit month between 01 and 12.")
            continue
        print("Month q returning:", month)
        return month
```

Using a blanket `except:` clause is never a good idea; in the above code I catch the `ValueError` raised by `int()` when you enter a non-integer value instead, and *raise* the same exception if you did enter an integer but it was not a value between 1 and 12 inclusive. That simplifies the 'not a month' error handling significantly.

Comment: May thanks Martijn. That is a nice solution. I appreciated the problem must be the 'print' referring back to the previoulsy returned 'none' values but didn't know how or why it could store them somewhere. I'd mistakenly assumed the final correct value would overwrite the value of month accourdingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try:
    month = int(input('What was the month [MM] which the installers were  updated/created by xxx?:'))
except:
    print("That was not a valid number. Please re-enter a 2 digit month")
    month_q()
    break
```

That should break stop the printing of incorrect months

Also, you should change

```
updatemonth = month_check(month)
print("Month q returning:", updatemonth)
return updatemonth
```

to:

```
updatemonth = month_check(month)
try:
    updatemonth
except NameError:
    updatemonth = None

if updatemonth is None:
    break
print("Month q returning:", updatemonth)
return updatemonth
```